# Find symbolic links leading to symbolic links

Tags: linux, symlink

I want to find symlinks that contain only multiple soft links.
I know how to list all files containing soft links but I want to show only files that contain multiple soft links

Comment: I mean file like fol.txt that contain two soft links (I think you are from Poland we can speak polish it will be easier)

Comment: Please don't speak Polish on here - I'd like to understand as well, and I don't think your English is the problem - it's actually very good!

Comment: I think the problem is the you confuse *file* with *file name*. You mean a text file containing multiple names of files that are actually soft links (symbolic links), right?

Comment: Example: file.txt -> softlink1 softlink2. My teacher says it's possible

Comment: Could you confirm or deny my understanding, please?

Comment: I deny it. Sorry. I can give you content of my task. In the user's directory tree, search for all files that have more than one symbolic link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
cd /usr/bin
find . -type l -exec bash -c '
    v=$(readlink "$1")
    [[ -L "$v" ]] && echo "$1"
' -- {} \;
```